# Simulate Location with Indoor Venue Routing

Tags: ios, here-api

I was able to calculate a route with my routing controller which returns a `NMAVenue3dCombinedRoute` object by following this tutorial:

https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics/maps-venue-3d-indoor-routing.html

Next, I want to simulate a user moving along the calculated route. I found `NMARoutePositionSource` which helps to simulate locations a long a route, but it only accepts a `NMARoute` object. I don't see any connections between `NMARoute` and `NMAVenue3dCombinedRoute`.

How do I pass `NMAVenue3dCombinedRoute` into `NMARoutePositionSource` so it can start generating location updates along a route? Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is not supported. Multimodal routes currently do not work with navigable NMARoute objects and related APIs.

Comment: Can I at least simulate a user moving along one of those routes within NMAVenue3dCombinedRoute?

Comment: Not with the current version. This maybe a feature for an upcoming version.